# Cannot start an agent

Tags: java, pug, agents-jade

I'm new with JADE and only trying to launch that say "Hello World! My name is smith" my code is the following :

```
package test;
import jade.core.Agent;

public class myFirstAgent extends Agent {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1274500864032189209L;
    
    protected void setup() {
        System.out.println("Hello World! My name is "+getLocalName());
        // Make this agent terminate
        doDelete();
    } 
}
```

I add the following Configuration :

> -gui jade.Boot smith:test.myFirstAgent

And I have the following errors :

> AVERTISSEMENT: WARNING: ignoring command line argument smith:test.myFirstAgent occurring after agents specification
>
> AVERTISSEMENT: Note that agent specifications must be separated by a semicolon character ";" without spaces
>
> AVERTISSEMENT: Cannot create an agent with no name. Class was jade.Boot

Can't get why, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do same command without jade.Boot
-gui smith:test.myFirstAgent